# Using 比 (bǐ) for comparison

Tags: grammar, comparison

I know how to use 比 in simple sentences like

> 哥哥比姐姐高 (my big brother is taller than my big sister)

Would it be used for other sentences like

> You learn more words by listening than by reading.

Answer (score 10):

"哥哥比姐姐高" is correct. The next sentence *"you learn more words by listening than by reading"* can be translated like:

> 听力比阅读更能提高你的词汇量
>   <sub>ting li bi yue du geng neng ti gao ni de ci hui liang</sub>

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started.

Comment: It can be also translated as: 与其通过阅读，倒还不如通过多听提高词汇量。It means "……rather than……".

Answer (score 2):

You could simply translate "than" into "比" in Chinese, but in Chinese, there are several different patterns for comparison.

grace's answer is good, but I think his translation is more likely a liberal translation(I would like to translate that Chinese sentence into English word by word: *Listening can enlarge your vocabulary more than reading* .You see, the subject and object are different from the original sentence). By translating the English words into Chinese one by one, you get:

> You learn more words by listening than by reading.
>   你    学习 更多  词汇  通过   听力    比  通过  阅读

To keep the sentence structure the same, I would like to use the pattern below:

> **相比于**阅读，通过听力你(可以*)学习更多的词汇。

*I think you need a model verb, such as "may" or "can" in your original sentence, that's why I add "可以" here.

Answer (score 1):

you already have the answer! just remember when using 比, having an adjective at the end makes it very easy to build sentences, such as 高 in your first example.

building on what you already know, a more colloquial way of saying your second sentence could be:

> 如果你要學單字，用聽的 *比* 用讀的 *快* 。
>
> (if you want to learn words, listening if faster than reading.)

you can also swap 快 with 有效 (effective) or 有效率 (efficient)。

Answer (score 1):

"You learn more words by listening than by reading." 直接翻译成 "用听的比用读的你学了更多单词。" 但是这句话听起来怪怪的。缺少了点什么信息。

所以下面两种选一个？

- "用听的比用读的你可以学会更多单词。" "You can learn more words by listening than by reading."
- "用听的比用读的你已经学了更多单词。" "You learned more words by listening than by reading."